# Formulario en PHP para actualizar MySQL ¿Update PDO - exec?

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios, pdo

Tengo que utilizar este codigo, no tengo otra opcion, no encuentro como realizar la asignacion en el **UPDATE** recibiendo los datos de un input

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$categoria = $_POST["categoria"];
$precio = $_POST["precio"];

$sql = "UPDATE `revistas` SET `nombre`= ".$nombre." , `categoria` = ".$categoria.", `precio` =". $precio." WHERE `id` =". $id;
$affectedrows = $db->exec($sql);
if(isset($affectedrows)) {
    echo "Record has been successfully updated";
}
```

**CODIGO ORIGINAL**

```
$sql = "UPDATE `vehiculo` SET `modelo`= 'Gol' , `modelo` = '2018'  ,`kilometros` = '10' WHERE `id` = 2" ;
$affectedrows = $db->exec($sql);
if(isset($affectedrows)) {
    echo "Record has been successfully updated";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Es preciso escribir un código seguro, el cual no puede ser con `exec`, ya que hay datos que no controlas y que un usuario mal intencionado puede modificar para inyectarte código malicioso. `exec` podría convenir en el caso de consultas que se deban ejecutar directamente de forma segura... no es el caso aquí.

La consulta que quieres, de forma segura tendría que:

- usar consultas preparadas, cambiando los valores por marcadores `?`
- crear un array con los valores que vienen en el POST
- pasar esos valores en forma de array en el `execute` (se puede hacer de otro modo si se prefiere, usando `bindParam`)
- para saber las filas afectadas usar `rowCount`

Este sería el código:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$categoria = $_POST["categoria"];
$precio = $_POST["precio"];

$sql = "UPDATE `revistas` SET `nombre` = ? , `categoria` = ?, `precio` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
$arrParams=array($nombre,$categoria,$precio,$id);
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($arrParams);

$affectedrows = $stmt->rowCount();
if($affectedrows > 0) {
    echo "Record has been successfully updated";
}
```